# CentOS VM on VMware ESXI: System UUID and Serial number not same

Tags: centos, vmware-vsphere, openshift-origin

We are running CentOS 7.9 with OKD cluster 3.11 on VMware ESXi 6.7.0.

As part of our activities, we are trying to setup cloud-provider integration with the VMware to have dynamic PV/PVC provisioning in place.

While following the [guide](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install_config/configuring_vsphere.html#install-config-configuring-vsphere), we come to know, that `product_serial` and `"System UUID"` of the virtual machines should be the same. ([bug-report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1727991#c15), [solution](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4256051))
We checked the files as suggested, and values were different.

Please see sample output from DMIdecode:

```
System Information
        Manufacturer: VMware, Inc.
        Product Name: VMware Virtual Platform
        Version: None
        Serial Number: VMware-56 4d 3e 3d 9c 26 28 68-25 ee 86 7d c8 a1 72 f4
        UUID: 3d3e4d56-269c-6828-25ee-867dc8a172f4
        Wake-up Type: Power Switch
        SKU Number: Not Specified
        Family: Not Specified
```

In addition to that we have checked another environment that is running on another hypervisor - openstack, and there values are identical.

What we also did try, is to change/force another value via `.vmx` files as suggested [here](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/17/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-C9B72CBC-662A-4330-9305-87070917D5F8.html), but that still did not make changes to the UUID, only to Serial Number.

In addition to that, the same is true for fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS release, System UUID and Serial do not match.

Question being, are we missing something on the vmWare configuration level or the OS itself?

How we checked:

```
$ cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_serial
$ cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid
$ oc describe node nodename | grep -i "System UUID"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the described issue is to change the .vmx file SMbios version:
acpi.smbiosVersion2.7 = "FALSE"
This will set SMBios version to 2.4 and serial together with UUID will be read properly.